# VB Script - Dynamic Arrays

Tags: vbscript

I would like to understand the dynamic array initializing. In the below code why the array size is not being set even after entering the value of "y". And both Lbound and Ubound is showing as 0 even after giving values to Y as 4, 5 or anything.

Please explain this to me. Thank You.

```
Dim i

Redim arr(y)

y = cint(InputBox("Enter value of y"))

Msgbox Lbound(arr)

Msgbox Ubound(arr)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should Redim *after* asking for the value.